# Is it necessary to close mongodb connection in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm new to nodejs and mongodb. in mongodb native driver website they close connection after each request but it seems like to be very slow and problematic in high traffic websites. I'm just curious to know is it necessary to do that or I can declare a global variable and reference that to DB like this:

```
var mongodbClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;

function connect() {
    mongodbClient.connect('connection string', function (err, mdb) {
        db = mdb;
    });
}

connect();

function insert(query, collection, fn) {
    db.collection(collection)
        .insert(query, function (er, da) {
        fn(er, da);
    });
}

function find(query, collection, fn) {
    db.collection(collection)
        .find(query).toArray(function (er, da) {
        fn(er, da);
    });
}
```

I don't want to use mongoose and prefer to learn and understand what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples available in documentation are not actually good for real life use cases.  If you are using a server framework you can normally connect to mongo and share reference to the connection throughout application. I use hapi and connect to server via a plugin which allows me to store the handle to open connection. This allows you to clean up on shutdown of server.  Their are many modules for managing mongo such as mongoose, waterline or [wadofgum-mongodb](https://github.com/simon-p-r/wadofgum-mongodb) which I have recently written.